# Replacements for ampersand and double-ampersand in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In Windows' native CMD processor, you can use `&` to string commands together so that one runs immediately after the other.  A `&&` will run the second command only if the first completes without error.

This is different from piping commands together with `|` in that output from the first command *is not* sent to the second command, the commands are just simply run one after the other and output for each is sent to its usual place.

However, I get an error when I try to use `&` or `&&` in PowerShell.  Are there similar functions available in PowerShell, or is this feature being deprecated?

Comment: This might help: [What are the PowerShell equivalent of Bash's && and || operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2416662)

Comment: An interesting question is if powershell's metaprogramming could be used to provide this functionality using `&&`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `&` operator in PowerShell is just the `;` or Semicolon.

The `&&` operator in PowerShell has to be run as an `if` statement.

```
Command ; if($?) {Command}
```

Example:

```
tsc ; if($?) {node dist/run.js}
```

Comment: Can this be chained? And does failure still send a non-zero exit message?

Comment: Since PowerShell Core v7, `&&` and `||` can be used directly.

Comment: This does not seem to work - if(git add -A) { if(git commit -a -m "comment") {git push}} whereas in unix this works as git add -A && git commit -a -m "comment" && git push.

Comment: @aaronsteers `; if($?)` can be chained.  For example, `[command1] ; if($?) { [command2] } ; if($?) { [command3] }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, which can be used roughly the same way:

```
function aa() {
    if($?) {
        $command = [string]::join(' ', $args[1..99])
        & $args[0] $command
    }
}
```

Now `&&` can be replaced with `; aa`, which while still not perfect is a lot more succinct.

```
cls && build
```

becomes

```
cls; aa build
```

Comment: Any non-stylistic reason why you're using `args[0]` and not `function aa ($cmd)`?

Comment: This is a brittle way to invoke commands; use _script blocks_ to pass commands around, and invoke those with `.`, not `&`, because the latter creates a child scope for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It is now possible to do it natively with Powershell 7

`Write-Output 'First' && Write-Output 'Second'`

> First
> Second

But if the first command fails (here note the `Write-Error`):

`Write-Error 'Bad' && Write-Output 'Second'`

> Bad

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipeline_chain_operators?view=powershell-7.3