# What is the ampersand sign (&) before commands in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I was trying out a command by typing the path to it, and when I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, this happened:

```
C:\> C:\Program Files\KeePassXC\keepass<TAB>
# became this:
C:\> & 'C:\Program Files\KeePassXC\keepassxc-cli.exe'
```

Does it simply evaluate a string? At least, I assume so as the path needs to be enclosed in quotes because of the spaces in it, and without `&` I get the following error:

```
C:\> 'C:\Program Files\KeePassXC\keepassxc-cli.exe' --help

At line:1 char:50
+ 'C:\Program Files\KeePassXC\keepassxc-cli.exe' --help
+                                                  ~~~~
Unexpected token 'help' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ 'C:\Program Files\KeePassXC\keepassxc-cli.exe' --help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The '--' operator works only on variables or on properties.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Would you link to the documentation? Thank you!

---

The threads discussing `&` ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/464109/replacements-for-ampersand-and-double-ampersand-in-powershell), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/345602/what-is-cmds-equivalent-to-bashs-ampersand-for-running-a-command-without-w)) are about something else completely (or I missed to find a connection).

Comment: That’s not Command Prompt. It’s PowerShell.

Comment: Just updated the question, thanks! My first foray into Windows after a decade of not using it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a call or invocation operator [Call operator &](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-):

> You can use the call operator to execute scripts using their
> filenames. The example below shows a script filename that contains
> spaces. When you try to execute the script, PowerShell instead
> displays the contents of the quoted string containing the filename.
> The call operator allows you to execute the contents of the string
> containing the filename.
>
> ```
> PS C:\Scripts> ".\script name with spaces.ps1"
> .\script name with spaces.ps1
>
> PS C:\Scripts> & ".\script name with spaces.ps1"
> Hello World!
> ```